# How to literally translate this sentence: 志愿者同时欣赏原作和画面元素被调整后的画作?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

另一个实验是这样，志愿者同时欣赏原作和画面元素被调整后的画作，包括静物画和抽象画。结果，几乎每个人都更喜欢原作。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 18.

Please help me understand the literal translation of this sentence: 志愿者同时欣赏原作和画面元素被调整后的画作.

I am at this point:

志愿者(the volunteers)同时(simultaneously)欣赏(enjoyed)原作(original work)和(and)画面(picture)元素(element)被(by or passive voice)调整(to adjust)后(after)的画作(painting or drawing)

Why google translates the 欣赏 as "viewed"? Volunteers viewed both the original...

At this clause: 画面元素被调整后, I really feel I am very far from understanding it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

欣赏 is "to appreciate/to enjoy/to admire (something) thru viewing of/look at it"; it is a more elegant way to say "看(view/look at)", which is the appropriate word for looking at and sensing the difference in paintings of different states - original vs altered.

志愿者(the volunteers)同时(at the same time)欣赏(look at)原作(the original work)和(and)画面元素(the pictorial elements)被(being)调整后的(adjusted/altered)画作(painting or drawing).

Now you can try to make it a better sentence in English.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand why 画面 is needed... Doesn't the sentence make the same sense without it? 志愿者同时欣赏原作和元素被调整后的画作

Comment: It is there for clarity - the elements(元素) that are on the other painting, not on anything else. Your sentence is understandable, but someone may intuitively ask before giving much thought:  "what elements?"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you could say enjoyed, but viewed fits better in this context.

画面元素被调整后的画作
painting surface elements (been) altered after de painting
paintings which had been altered

另一个实验是这样，
Another experiment was like this,
志愿者同时欣赏原作和画面元素被调整后的画作，
(the) volunteers viewed the original works and altered versions of them,
包括静物画和抽象画。
including still-life and abstract paintings.

结果，几乎每个人都更喜欢原作。
Result: almost everyone preferred the originals.